# User list administration managment

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a list of user for a site, mainly using a unique ID for each members.

I need to have a button after each name to delete or modify but i can't find how to do it properly, here's the code !

```
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY ID_Usager");
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
          {
             echo "<form method='post'>"; 
              echo "<tr>";
              echo "<td>" . $row['Pseudo'] . "</td>";
              echo "<td>" . $tempID . "</td>";
              echo "<td>" . $row['Email'] . "</td>";
              echo "<td>" . $row['Status'] . "<input type='submit' name='delete[" . $tempID . "]' value='Delete'> <input type='submit' name='modify[" . $tempID . "]' value='Modify'> </td>";
              echo "</tr>";
              echo "</form>";
          }
```

(I have skipped some table code..)
So this show as :

> Vincent     25625   [DELETE] [MODIFY]

So what I was think, when i click submit, it reload the page, i look if the Post Delete[] is empty, or modify is empty, ...

```
        if(!empty($_POST['delete']))
        {

            $test[] =  $_GET['delete[]']; ---- LINE 163 ERROR...

            //Delete from blablabla userID = $test;
        }
        else
        {
            ... check for modify then blablabla.    

        }
```

But its not working, i get an error.

```
 Notice: Undefined index: delete[] in C:\wamp\www\VMAD\admin_usagers.php on line 163
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `[]` is the problem. It should be

```
$test = $_POST['delete'];
```

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: delete in C:\wamp\www\VMAD\admin_usagers.php on line 163

Same error :(

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice you had the form set for `POST`. See the edit.

Comment: I changed it, and $test is now ARRAY (in the echo), how can i reach the ID number? Thank you!

Comment: Personally, if it was me, I would put the ID in the `value` attribute of a hidden `INPUT` value, and not the submit button.

Comment: Thanks, i've put a hidden value with the user ID in it, and it's working!

Comment: You should really have two different `FORM`s, too, one for each action (using CSS make each inline).

Comment: what makes this practice better?

Comment: I remember having problems with one form trying to do what you're doing (it's been a while). With two forms, you can more easily customize the criteria you test for. For instance, I would use a `GET` value with the action, such as `?action=delete` and use the `POST` value to determine which to delete.